# Classification based on likelihood toward maximum or minimum of survey score

Tags: machine-learning, classification

So, I'm developing a model to classify a dataset into risk levels.

The dataset is labeled based on the survey score that the subject comepleted. 
Now, from this survey score, I'll have maximum and minimum of score. I've read some paper they label the data set as 'High' or 'Low', based on the overall average score of the survey.

What I'm curious is that is there any method to develop a model to classify based on the likeli hood (For example, a data instance is 60% toward the maximum score), or the possible method is to divide the score based on decile or quartile.

I'm still new to this kind of problem, so any advise/answers would be really appreciated. Any keywords for me to search on would also be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to decide the number of risk levels. For instance, for a two-level assignment (i.e. high and low), scores between minimum and median can be assigned to *low* and scores between median and maximum can be assigned to *high*.

Similarly, a 4-level assignment can be made using minimum, 1st quartile, median,3rd quartile and the maximum. This way you can obtain a balanced dataset with respect to labels (i.e. each label has the same number of observations)

Then, you can apply any classification technique to provide a model to your problem.